# How to deal with writing an API endpoint that requires some other API requests be made in advance?

Tags: web-services, api-design

I have an API endpoint for adding a note, but when this API is used from the GUI, it's guaranteed that some things have happened before making this request... For example, let's say I'm adding tags of a note both in the note itself, AND, in a separate collection specific to the tags. So when the user adds/removes/changes some attributes of tags in the GUI, requests are made one by one and the tags collection will be affected independently, however, if the user makes an API request, they can (inadvertently) circumvent a step very easily, and for example, add a tag to the note WITHOUT having added it to the tags collection before... . How can such a scenario be dealt with when writing a service? For some reasons, this data CANNOT be kept only in one of the two places, both must exist.

So in short, the resource has some "dependent" resources, but those are kept up to date with it when tweaked in the GUI, however, making such a request:

```
POST /api/resources HTTP/1.1
// body containing dependent resources...
```

can get them out of sync.

I'm not sure about the terminology of web service design so the title might be difficult to understand, but this question is indeed about "keeping the integrity of data when it's kept in two places in the database, when altering one of them using an API (the other one must remain meaningfully correct and in sync with the latest state).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be at least two things that can be done in this case:

1. Do both operations in one request. I don't like this one personally, as in my case it will mean multiple writes to the database which can be expensive.
2. Return an error status code (4xx, maybe 409). I like this one, it can also be made completely clear in a message to the requester what they should have done prior to making that request.